# Do you know how to handle this time stamp

Tags: java, timestamp

I have a question regarding a strange timestamp format.

I got a csv file where one column is named "lastLogIn"

In this field I find values like these:
1259935150
1260713821
1391626756
1263750047

Unfortunately it is not a standard Java "millis" value.
All I know about the originating system is, that it is written in PHP and data is stored in a MySQL db on a Linux system.

Do you know how to convert this values into java Date object?

cheers,
christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are Unix timestamps, they are in seconds, so in order to get Java miliseconds you can do the following :

```
int unixTime = 1259935150;
Date time = new Date(unixTime*1000L);
```